# Does priority in java real affects the order of execution?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

Here is the code

[Code on Gist](https://gist.github.com/Yubo-Cao/c1bedb99502163d5c3219d9466dfc594)

With the curiosity of priority in Java, I created the above test, and I run it few times.  But suprisingly, the difference between using MAX_PRIORITY and MIN_PRIORITY are microscopic, and always neglibile. I check my code several times, and I am not sure whether it is my code has problem or the java's priority mechanism it self tend to act this way.

Thanks for your consideration and time!

Comment: Trying to use priority for timing is implementation-dependent, flaky, and unreliable. Write code that's well-defined under the JMM instead.

Comment: I've never seen thread priority or even process priority make much of a difference, except in the case of process priority when the system was overloaded, and I generally found that fiddling with priorities was the problem, not the solution.